# What's the difference between a solar furnace and my eyeball if I glance at the Sun? Besides water at the focal plane, is it basically just f/no.?

Tags: thermodynamics, optics

In [this answer to *Can large scientific telescopes observe the Moon without being damaged?*](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/45524/7982) I've forwarded the notion that the intensity per unit area at the focal plane of an imaging system looking at the Moon is primarily dependent on the inverse square of the f/no.

Since the f/no. of a human eye eye (17/6 = 2.8) and the [Vera C. Reuben telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vera_C._Rubin_Observatory) (10,310/8,360 = 1.23) are related by roughly $\sqrt{5}$ I said that the intensity (power per unit area) of the Moon on the telescope's focal plane is only about 5x brighter than at the back of our retina.

I also noted there that since various types of point-and-shoot cameras (from cell phones all the way to some mirrorless and physical shutterless DLSRs) aren't instantly damaged if the Sun happens to be in the field of view (say at an afternoon at the beach) their sensors and filters can withstand power densities much higher than a telescope looking at the Moon, therefore the Moon won't damage the CCD of a telescope.

Below that answer there's a comment that it's *the absolute size of the aperture* that determines how hot something gets rather than the f/no.

The arguments in comments go something like:

- our 6 mm aperture eye is not damaged if we glance at the Sun (though we can quickly bleach photoreceptors and do real damage if we stare)
- a 5 to 10 cm magnifying glass can burn paper
- the ~50 meter aperture [Odeillo solar furnace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odeillo_solar_furnace) heats samples "3,500 °C in a few seconds".

My feeling is that ignoring absorption of some wavelengths in our eye components, partial transparency of the retina and the high specific heat and thermal conductivity of water and just looking at the optics, a solar furnace the size of a human eye can reach the same sample temperatures as one that's 50 meters in diameter, the primary metric being the focal ratio or f/no.

**I think that If I made a 17 mm / 50 meter = ~1:3000 replica of the solar furnace and its sample holder, it would also be able to reach a sample temperature of "3,500 °C in a few seconds".** The key factor being the f/no. and not the absolute diameter in meters or millimeters.

Is that basically correct?

Are there issues with heat flow towards the edges in the sample? Could those be address in practice?

---

Note that *I have not asked* about systems so small that diffraction effects affect the image size of the Sun.

[image: Le jubilé du grand four solaire d’Odeillo dans les Pyrénées-Orientales]

Source: [Le jubilé du grand four solaire d’Odeillo dans les Pyrénées-Orientales](https://tecsol.blogs.com/mon_weblog/2019/07/le-jubil%C3%A9-du-grand-four-solaire-dodeillo-dans-les-pyr%C3%A9n%C3%A9es-orientales.html)

[image: Schematic of the 1000 kW solar furance. The parabolic reflector has a focal length of 59 feet, is 130 feet hight and 175 feet wide...]

> Schematic of the 1000 kW solar furance. The parabolic reflector has a focal length of 59 feet, is 130 feet hight and 175 feet wide...

Source: [High Temperature Solar Energy Pamphlet (archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20161003072910/http://www.gtri.gatech.edu/history/files/media/other-publications/High_Temp_Solar_Energy_Pamphlet.pdf)

Comment: Only vaguely related, I think, but perhaps worth a look? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19954/59023

Comment: Also, to what does f/no. refer?

Comment: @honeste_vivere that's related but overkill, I think this is a self-contained optics + heat diffusion question. "focal ratio or f/no." two words for the same thing. Camera lenses have 1.4, 2, 2.8, 4, 5.6, 8, 11, 16... etc.

Comment: Yeah I figured but thought it worth mentioning just for completeness sake.

Comment: Aren't you just asking about etendue here?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft "Aren't you just asking..." No.

Comment: OK, well, can e.g. a 0.5 mm $\phi$ magnifying glass burn paper?  At some point a geometric focus calculation, including spherical defocus effects,  should show the maximum power density achievable for a given size lens.  You are correct that energy dissipation matters, since of course both conductive transfer and black body reradiation will matter at some point.